# Filtering more than 100 columns of pyspark df on same condition

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark df with 200 columns which is actually containing percentage of change from previous month to current month. I need to find out df with all the columns have change greater than 10% in single filter query or may be using some othere.

General idea

```
df=df.filter(c for c in df.columns if df.c>10)
```

Comment: any paticular reason for you to unaccept my answer ? If something is wrong, you can tell me, i'll fix it.

Comment: Hi Steven, I tried it but did not get answer as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply do that :

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.filter(df[col]>10)
```

---

anoother method :

```py
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(
    lambda a,b: a.filter(df[b]>10),
    df.columns,
    df
)
```

---

and another one :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

where_condition = reduce(
    lambda a,b: a & b,
    [F.col(col)>10 for col in df.columns]
)

df.where(where_condition)
```